# How to Order BY without having Column in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS-SQL and I have a table like this:

```
Count  Code
1      A
2      C
3      A
4      B
5      C
6      B
```

I need to only to get Distinct Row of the Code Column but I need to keep the Order of the Column to create a Comma Delimited String like this:

```
    A, C, B
```

I have tried the following code to not get an SQL Error of Msg 145, Level 15 - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

```
SELECT @tlist = ISNULL(@tlist+', ','') + Code 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.Code  
     FROM @Table t)
```

but I get an output of A, B, C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you don't want `distinct`.  You want `group by`:

```
select t.code
from @Table t
group by t.code
order by min(count)
```

You can order by columns not mentioned in the `select` clause.

To get the comma delimited list as a single variable, use this technique:

```
select stuff((select ', '+t.code
              from @Table t
              group by t.code
              order by min(count)
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 2, '')
```

`Order by` in a subquery is generally undefined.  And, your method of concatenating the list together in order is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: By using the group by as a subquery I get the error Msg 1033, Level 15 - The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.  But when I add TOP 100 between the SELECT and t.code it works.

Answer (score 3):

order them in your subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Code  
FROM @Table t
ORDER BY t.Code
```

Comment: . . The questioner appears to want the ordering by the first column, not alphabetically by code.

Comment: The addition of the ORDER BY t.Code throws the error Msg 1033, Level 15, The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: try, `SELECT @tlist = ISNULL(@tlist+', ','') + Code 
FROM 
 (
  SELECT CODE
  FROM
  (
   SELECT DISTINCT t.Code  
   FROM @Table t
  ) xx
  ORDER BY CODE
 ) `